# Cargar hojas de estilos asincronicamente?

Tags: javascript, css3, vue.js

Estoy construyendo una SPA y llega un momento en el que necesito insertar una hoja de estilos nueva y retirar la vieja.

no me gusta la solucion:

```
 $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="new_estyles.css" type="text/css" />');
 $("LINK[href='styles.css']").remove();
```

Porque la pagina da un salto entre las hojas de estilos que hace que se vea mal.

intente con esta solución pero tampoco me funciona:

```
$('#preloader').show();
axios.get('estilos').then(res=>{
    $('head').append('<style>'+ res.data + '</style>');
    $('#preloader').hide();
});
```

Comment: y si haces el biding con una clase?

Comment: Lamentablemente son muchos los estilos que cambian. Lo hago cuando un usuario sube de categoría, y por lo tanto, todo el diseño de pagina web cambia de estilos. (no pongo todos los estilos es una sola hoja porque no todos los usuarios podrán crecer su perfil).